How to make a draggable bottom sheet that can affect body of scaffold
I am trying to make a chat app. It will support emojis, so I wanted to make an emoji picker widget like whatsapp where it opens like a showModalBottomSheet with the drag handle and everything but also affect the body of the chat when being dragged. it also provides smooth transition between keyboard and emoji picker.
I tried multiple ideas to achieve this like utilizing scaffold's bottomSheet or even drawer and then showing them dynamically but it doesn't fit to my needs. I tried putting the emojis gridview in the body itself but I don't know how to make it draggable like a bottom sheet and affect the chat body which is expanded. does anyone have any idea on this feature or how to implement it ?

I didn't quite understand your question. Could you please clarify or provide more details, such as images or a video, if possible?
Also, if you're not already using this approach, please give it a try.
showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      isScrollControlled: true,
      backgroundColor: context.colorStyles.background,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(16.r)),
  ),
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return Wrap(
  children: [
  Column()]);
});


the idea is when a user presses on the emoji button, it will show the emoji gridview from the bottom, just like Whatsapp, the gridview will also have a drag handle to show that this gridview is expandable to show more icons. when dragged, it will resize the chat body
